Sharing SQLite database between two ASP.NET Core servers running in Docker
I have two ASP.NET Core web servers (backend+frontend) running in two separate Windows Docker containers. They both have their own db contexts and app startups add them as a scoped service with Dependency Injection. It's a SQLite database, which is stored in a Docker bind mount on the host so that they can both access it.
Everything works as expected while containers are running. However, when I shut down either container (CTRL+C from docker-compose console or docker stop) and there was at least one call to the db (even not writing but just select) through EFCore, the shutting down takes a longer time (~30sec vs. usual 1-2sec) and server exits with -1 code (4294967295.)
DI is supposed to auto-manage the scope of the db contexts and dispose them - and that's what I see in the logs. But it seems that still for some reason one server container cannot stop gracefully if the second one is still running and there was at least one db access.
Any suggestions on how to diagnose the -1 exit code would be appreciated.
